# in rename_v2_pywrap_file_io.RenameFile tensorflow.python.framework.errors_

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I have been trying to train a custom object detector using Tensorflow 2. But I can't seem to resolve this error. Any help will be really appreciated.

- Python 3.8.5
- Tensorflow version 2.3.0

---

I've ran the command:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample>python model_main_tf2.py
--pipeline_config_path=C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample\efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32/pipeline.config
--model_dir=C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample\efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32 --alsologtostderr
```

---

It looks like it was running at some point?

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',) I1009 19:50:50.048526  2352 mirrored_strategy.py:341] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',) INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None I1009 19:50:50.098694  2352 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False I1009 19:50:50.100239  2352 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False I1009 19:50:50.174606  2352 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:143] EfficientDet EfficientNet backbone version: efficientnet-b4 I1009 19:50:50.175298  2352 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:145] EfficientDet BiFPN num filters: 224 I1009 19:50:50.177546  2352 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:146] EfficientDet BiFPN num iterations: 7 I1009 19:50:50.209522  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=32 output=48 I1009 19:50:50.353352  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=32 output=48 I1009 19:50:50.354059  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=16 output=24 I1009 19:50:50.821037  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=16 output=24 I1009 19:50:50.821037  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=24 output=32 I1009 19:50:51.793773  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=24 output=32 I1009 19:50:51.793773  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=40 output=56 I1009 19:50:52.919260  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=40 output=56 I1009 19:50:52.920256  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=80 output=112 I1009 19:50:54.440330  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=80 output=112 I1009 19:50:54.441295  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=112 output=160 I1009 19:50:56.034809  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=112 output=160 I1009 19:50:56.034809  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=192 output=272 I1009 19:50:58.116659  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=192 output=272 I1009 19:50:58.117657  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=320 output=448 I1009 19:50:58.654929  2352 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=1280 output=1792
```

---

And I get this:

```
 File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_loop
    manager.save()
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 819, in save
    self._record_state()
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 722, in _record_state
    update_checkpoint_state_internal(
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 247, in update_checkpoint_state_internal
    file_io.atomic_write_string_to_file(coord_checkpoint_filename,
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 570, in atomic_write_string_to_file
    rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 529, in rename
    rename_v2(oldname, newname, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Meadow\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 545, in rename_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RenameFile(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to rename: C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample\efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint.tmpd3b2a635f96d4952a2e13e36f0919602 to: C:\Users\Meadow\ECD_sample\efficientdet_d4_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```